# Error when import supercluster in typescript (TypeError: Cannot set property 'options' of undefined)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-maps

When I import supercluster in typescript, I have encounter this error. Please feel free to comment.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:86 TypeError: Cannot set property 'options' of undefined

    This error is located at:
        in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
        in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

**Updated**

I got the exception(alert in ios simulator) when the program executes the following function.

```
const cluster = supercluster({
        radius: 40,
        maxZoom: 16,
    });
```

[image]

Comment: It would certainly help if you posted what's at `ExceptionsManager.js` at line 86 and thereabouts, as well as how you're doing the import.

Comment: It seems Typescript is incompatible with mapbox's supercluster.

Comment: TypeScript compiles into JavaScript, so if this `supercluster` thing works with JavaScript (I assume it in fact is itself JavaScript), it can certainly work with TypeScript. Again I'd ask how you're doing the import.

Comment: @kshetline import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import supercluster from 'supercluster';
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, after installed [@types/supercluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/supercluster), the error has gone.

```
yarn add @types/supercluster

or 

npm install --save @types/supercluster
```